# Can I presolve an ILP model before optimization?

Tags: r, gurobi

**I am getting out of memory while building the model. Is there any way, to reduce the model while building it using existing functions?**

**Details:** Assume I have the following model (from the docs [here](https://www.gurobi.com/resources/getting-started/mip-basics) section Presolve. The real code also uses sparse matrices, so this is just to figure out what can be done further):

```
min 2*x1 - 5*x2 + 3*x3 + 10*x4
s.t.
x1 + x2 + x3 = 15 (1)
x1 <= 7           (2)
x2 <= 3           (3)
x3 <= 5           (4)
x4 > 1            (5)
```

Clearly the only way that all of these constraints can be satisfied is if `x1 = 7, x2 = 3, and x3 = 5`. 
My goal is to reduce dimensions "on the fly" if possible. In pseudo-code:

```
model <- build_model(objective_function,
                     restrictions (1) to (4))
model1 <- presolve_model(model)
model2 <- build_model(objective_function1,
                     restrictions model1 and (5))
result <- gurobi::gurobi(model2)
```

Where `model1` only consists of the variable `x4` as `x1 = 7, x2 = 3, and x3 = 5` (presolved). Is this possible?

**Comments**:

- In Gurobi's Python interface you can perhaps use `presolve.model()`? See [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/py_model_presolve.html)
  but I have no clue how that is done. I also didn't find a possibility to return the presolved model from `gurobi::gurobi()`. 
  However, the last two lines in the reprducible example return the model as a file - but NOT the presolved, as can be seen from the example.
- Gurobi does presolving, as can be seen from the parameter [Presolve](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/presolve.html#parameter:Presolve).
- Experts might want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/jeffreyhanson/rgurobi) package.
- Maybe it is related to the `vbasis` and `cbasis` argument from Gurobi? The docs state

> Finally, if the final solution is a basic solution (computed by
>   simplex), then `vbasis` and `cbasis` will be present.

**Reproducible example**:

```
model <- list()
model$A          <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 
                             1, 0, 0, 0, 
                             0, 1, 0, 0, 
                             0, 0, 1, 0, 
                             0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 5, ncol = 4, byrow = T)
model$obj        <- c(2, -5, 3, 10)
model$modelsense <- "min"
model$rhs        <- c(15, 7, 3, 5, 1)
model$sense      <- c('=', '<=', '<=', '<=', '>')
model$vtype      <- 'I'
params <- list(OutputFlag = 1, Presolve = 2, TimeLimit = 3600)

result <- gurobi::gurobi(model, params) # optimize

# gurobi::gurobi_write(model, 'mymodel.mps') # output to file
# gurobi::gurobi_write(model, 'mymodel.lp') # output to file
```

Comment: Sorry not clear... are you trying to get the pre-solved problem or solve the original problem exploiting pre-solve ? If it's the latter, I think that gurobi default presolve should be able to do as much as possible, if you're getting out-of-memory then your problem is really too big and you should think to change the formulation

Comment: @digEmAll In your words, I tried to get the pre-solved problem (in order to reduce the problem while building).

Comment: Oh I got it, so you're getting out-of-memory error while building the problem... mmh unfortunately the package you posted doesn't seem to expose `presolve.model()` function

Comment: @digEmAll That's true! That's the reason for my question... I thought I'd better ask here before I start to develop a function for the next weeks / months ;-) Do you think my idea is good? I googled quite some time and it seems nobody goes along that line...

Comment: Makes sense...well, it depends on the memory you will save by presolving... is your problem supposed to have a lot of variables with implied bounds, useless constraints etc ? In this case it makes sense, otherwise you're just going to postpone the out-of-memory error ;)

Comment: BTW, since python has a better interface to gurobi, can't you use that ?

Comment: @digEmAll I'd like to avoid to start with another language right now...

Comment: Writing the presolved model is unlikely to save significant memory, especially since the operating system should swap out any memory from the original model (before presolve). It would be better to understand why you're running out of memory, but that's a different question.

Comment: This might be a really unhelpful suggestion, but in the example your example, you create the A matrix using R's "matrix" class, [have you tried using a sparse matrix class from the Matrix package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparseMatrix.html)?

Comment: @paleo13 Good point, but this is already implemented. I should say that in the question - edit follows ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gurobi: Save model after presolve for reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496002/gurobi-save-model-after-presolve-for-reuse)

Comment: @GregGlockner Is there an analog to Matlab's `m.presolve()` for R? I think this is for what I am looking for.

Comment: @Christoph: As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496002/gurobi-save-model-after-presolve-for-reuse: "Gurobi lets you access the presolved model, but only from the Python API"

Comment: @GregGlockner ok, I thought this could have changed with release 8.0 ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with v8.0. As @GregGlockner stated:

As stated in this stackoverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496002/gurobi-save-model-after-presolve-for-reuse) "Gurobi lets you access the presolved model, but only from the Python API"